# How to Display Custom Meta Box only on Specific Page IDs

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I am using [Magic Fields 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields-2/) for custom meta boxes and custom fields, but this situation pertains to any meta box.

I have a custom meta box that I want to display on only 3 specific page IDs.

```
function mf_1_remove_meta_boxes() {

    if( !in_array($_GET['post'], array('194','185','2') ) ):
        remove_meta_box( 'mf_1', 'page', 'normal' );
}
```

### UPDATE

Using [Bainternet's solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/99933/14558), the code works. That being said, a new issue became apparent. When a new page is created, the meta box is visible immediately, then disappears once the page is saved, since the ID does not match an ID that has been specified.

### UPDATE 2

The code above has been modified to correct the issue with the meta box appearing on a new (unsaved) page. It has also been modified to a complete and working code. The meta box will be removed for all users.

To remove the meta box for everyone except admins:

```
function mf_1_remove_meta_boxes() {

    if( !is_admin())
        return;

    if( !in_array($_GET['post'], array('194','185','2') ) ):
        remove_meta_box( 'mf_1', 'page', 'normal' );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and cleaner solution would be to use !in_array ex:

```
function mf_1_remove_meta_boxes() {

    if( !is_admin() && !isset( $_GET['post'] ) )
        return;

    if( !in_array($_GET['post'], array('194','185','2') ) )
        remove_meta_box( 'mf_1', 'page', 'normal' );
}
```

this way you can just add the ids in the array and as many as you want

Comment: Thanks! The code needs a colon - `if( !in_array($_GET['post'], array('194','185','2') ) ):` otherwise a 500 error is returned. SE won't let me edit a single character. Other than that, works great.

Comment: A new issue became apparent after using this code. I have added an update to the question.

Comment: The colon is needed only if you are using the keyword endif.

Comment: using the exact code i posted will never give you 500.

Comment: Hmmm... It did yesterday, but I tested it again and it didn't. I must have missed something before. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`if($_GET['post'] != 194 || $_GET['post'] != 185 || $_GET['post'] != 2)`

It should work like this.

Comment: Thanks! The code needs a colon - `if($_GET['post'] != 194 || $_GET['post'] != 185 || $_GET['post'] != 2):` otherwise a 500 error is returned. SE won't let me edit a single character. Other than that, works great.

Comment: Either a colon (`:`) or a curly brace (`{`).